# Getting unexpected '@' error under postman Test tab

Tags: postman

I am a learner in postman and do not have much experience in programming/scripting.

Here the issue.

Used POST api request - For getting the access token;

Used POST api request - To create an account;

Used POST api request - To cancel an account with CancellationReason

Need to crosscheck the cancellation details (some fields like cancellationReason) in web application.

In order to avoid manually check, i have used GET request api like below

- by passing all the mapped fields (as per web application) in the GET request end url
  (i.e. by sending the details in fetch_xml query parameter in the end url) in order to get those required fields returned.

Now i got a successful response with status code.

After that i want to compare the fetched values (from the response body) ... VS.... to the data i passed while cancelling the account (i.e. in POST api request - To cancel the account) and make sure both are same.

After that under Test tab - I have updated query like below, however it throwing an Unexpected '@' error (as the below query contains '@' in middle of the field name)

**tests["Verify the CancellationReason matches"] = pm.expect(data._usr_cancellationReason_value@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue).to.eql("CancellationReason");**

Can someone please help me to understand whether i should remove this @symbol or should replace with something else ?

Here is the response body:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://hfrdcompanies.integrationdev01.crm3.cs.com/api/data/v9.1/$metadata#hfrd_workorders(_usr_cancellationchannel_value,usr_CancellationChannel,_usr_workorderreason_value,usr_WorkOrderReason,hfrd_workorderid,usr_cancellationuser,_usr_cancellationsource_value,usr_CancellationSource,hfrd_name,usr_CancellationChannel(),usr_AccountReason(),usr_CancellationSource())",
    "value": [
        {
            "@odata.etag": "W/\"2345234523\"",
            "_usr_cancellationchannel_value@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue": "Mobile App",
            "_usr_cancellationchannel_value": "acefsdflin89-f9jf07-e969f1-a245nk11-00jnfnafn9799fc2a",
            "_usr_Accountreason_value@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue": "Customer Inactive",
            "_usr_Accountreason_value": "bde1234522-d45662-e2711-a84561-0007354a2d5c2a",
            "hfrd_Accountid": "89025sf3-c668f-e7811-a4331-00asdhh3ab9bd1c",
            "usr_cancellationuser": "Testuser08 ABC",
            "_usr_cancellationsource_value@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue": "MOBILE",
            "_usr_cancellationsource_value": "6c23asdf-c562-e411-a841-00asdfa",
            "hfrd_name": "FP-WK-1000000642"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to validate the bold row

Comment: What is the response body? You're mixing the old and new syntax in that test so I have no idea what's going on  if you ad an example of the response, it will be easy to give you a working solution.

Comment: I have added the response body now.

Comment: Would you also be able to format that in a code block 

Comment: I attempted to format the response body - Is this was it looks like in Postman?